# What columns to include on filtered index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

Let's say there is a table called T1

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
  GID INT NOT NULL,
  Attrib1 BIT NOT NULL,
  Attrib1Date DATE NOT NULL,
  Attrib2 BIT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY (GID)
)
```

Now, I'm creating indexes for query, where only rows with Attrib1 equal 1 or Attrib2 equal 1 are interesting. Let's say there are only 20% of rows like that.

*Please, do not concern about Attrib1 to Attribe2 corelation - they are given only for two separate examples.*

It's obvious to use filtered indexes - I mean: INDEX-es with WHERE clause. But question is what columns to include?

**Sample queries:**

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Attrib1 = 1 ORDER BY Attrib1Date
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Attrib2 = 1
```

**Example and question 1)**

Which INDEX is more correct?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib1
ON T1 (Attrib1, Attrib1Date)
WHERE Attrib1 = 1
```

OR

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib1
ON T1 (Attrib1Date, Attrib1)
WHERE Attrib1 = 1
```

OR

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib1
ON T1 (Attrib1Date)
WHERE Attrib1 = 1
```

**Example and question 2)**

Is it correct to build filtered index containing only column by which is filtered, like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib2
ON T1 (Attrib2)
WHERE Attrib2 = 1
```

Comment: [Some behaviour to consider when choosing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10897198/73226)

Answer (score 2):

First, dispelling the misconception:

> Let's say there are only 20% of rows like that... It's obvious to use
>   filtered indexes

No, it's not obvious at all.  I think the index needs to be around 1% selectivity to sometimes be considered.  Commonly, the threshold is quoted at 5%.  There's an article about it but I just can't remember where. Search for it on Google.

On your 3 variants

> CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib1 ON T1 (Attrib1, Attrib1Date)
>   WHERE Attrib1 = 1

Because of SQL Server's implementation of filtered indexes, Attrib1 is required in the index key.  Having it at position 1 doesn't make it very selective, though.

> CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib1 ON T1 (Attrib1Date, Attrib1)
>   WHERE Attrib1 = 1

This one is more selective than the above, and would be preferable.  The pre-condition is used to check the applicability of the filtered index, but after that, the **regular** query engine takes over, which will do the normal selectivity checks etc.

> CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib1 ON T1 (Attrib1Date)
>   WHERE Attrib1 = 1

For the reason stated above, this one is less desirable, because the processing goes:

1. Query contains `WHERE Attrib1 = 1` -> this index can be considered (with other potentials)
2. Is Attrib1Date selective enough?
3. The index contains (Attrib1Date + record-pointer) => can these service the request, including the `WHERE Attrib1 = 1` condition

It fails at #3

> CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Attrib2 ON T1 (Attrib2)
>   WHERE Attrib2 = 1

Yes, you would do this if only to get the index created, and the inclusion of the column is for the regular query optimizer/engine that takes over beyond the `filtered index applicability` check.

Comment: Storing the redundant additional column in the filtered index is unfortunately often required per my link under the question.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've looked through the SO question and connect issue, tried a few things and summarized my understanding. The implementation sort of makes sense, for performance reasons and for not creating two branches within "query optimizer" for filtered indexes.